# ActionView::MissingTemplate in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in rails and I want to implement chat in my rails app 
following http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye, 
but i m unable to render

controller :

```
def index @messages = Chat.all // all available chats
```

I get the following error:

```
Missing partial chats/chat with {:handlers=>[:builder, :erb, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/swagata/Desktop/swagata_new/swagata/app/views"
  * "/home/swagata/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p160@swagata/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
```

I tried creating a partial name _chat.js.erb, but with no luck.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Rails is trying to render an HTML snippet, but the only partial you've provided is marked as being a Javascript snippet.

You probably want an HTML-erb partial called _chat.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Create chat.erb and check if it's working or not

Comment: its working but from chat.erb to render _message.html.erb is not happened

Comment: I think can u add respond_to block in action and create chat.html.erb and render partial format.html{render :partial=>''},Currently i don't remember but you can explicitly set template format also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a json call to render messages;
in your controller

```
def index
  @messages = Chat.all
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render "chat" }
  end 
end
```

and in your view file, there should be a chat.js.erb file without underscore. 
And your chat.js.erb may contain for example;

`$('#chat').html("<%=j render '/messages' ");`    line to render messages at the div with id "chat".

and at the same directory there should be a _messages.html.erb file to render @messages.

Comment: thanks for u r answer $('#chat').html("<%=j render '/messages' ") this line is unable to rnder messages line